# Факультативна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Факультативна ли запятая в приведенных ниже предложениях? Или ее обязательно нужно ставить?

> Мужчина намеренно задел каждого из них своими широкими(,) нелепо высоко поднятыми плечами.
>
> Она смотрела на меня большими(,) сверкающими в темноте глазами.

Нужно ли в этих случаях как-то отделять оборот? Если, например, "широкими" и "большими" переместить за обороты, то никакие запятые не напрашиваются.
А вот как действовать в указанных конструкциях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Мужчина намеренно задел каждого из них своими широкими, нелепо высоко поднятыми плечами.**

**Она смотрела на меня большими, сверкающими в темноте глазами.**

Запятая ставится, потому что

> за одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным оборотом, то есть причастием с зависимым словом: Чёрные, гладко причёсанные волосы. ([2.3.2. Однородные и неоднородные определения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html))